# Representing a bijection as a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors

Is it possible to represent a bijection using matrices? For example, if I have a bijection from a set of vectors back onto itself. A vector in the set could be  v = [10 2 11], and the mapping would be 10 -> 2, 2 -> 11, and 11 -> 10 so that v' = [ 11 2 10]. Another vector in the set, y = [2 11 10] would be mapped to y' = [11 10 2]. Does there exist a matrix such that v' = Av and y' = Ay for all permutations of the vectors in the set?

Comment: Yes, if the map is linear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.  They're called [permutation matrices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation_matrix).

More generally, the collection of bijective maps among a finite set (i.e., "permutations") forms a group.  The study of representing groups with matrices is called representation theory.